# Kubernetes Externalname service - how to connect

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We have two clusters. cluster1 has namespace- test1 and a service running as clusterip
we have to call that service from another cluster(cluster2) from namespace dev1.

I have defined externalname service in cluster2 pointing to another externalname service in cluster1.
And externalname service in cluster1 points to the original service running as clusterip.

In cluster2:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service
  namespace: dev1
  labels:
    app: service
spec:
  selector:
    app: service
  type: ExternalName
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalName: service2.test.svc.cluster.local
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

In cluster1:Externalname service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service2
  namespace: test1
  labels:
    app: service
spec:
  selector:
    app: service
  type: ExternalName
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalName: service1.test1.svc.cluster.local
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

in cluster1 clusterip service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service1
  namespace: test1
  labels:
    app: service1
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9099
      targetPort: 9099
  selector:
    app: service1
  clusterIP: 102.11.20.100
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

But, there is no hit to the service in cluster1. I tried to add spec:port:9099 in externalname services as well, still it does not work.

What could be the reason. Nothing specific in logs too

Comment: Please ignore any indentation or name errors, could be just while typing here. but actually things in correct name and syntax.

Comment: Are you certain both clusters can access cluster IPs natively? Usually most providers set up firewalls or similar to prevent that. Cluster IPs work inside the cluster, not always outside, as the name kind of implies.

Comment: That's right, I got answer today from other team members that clusters are on different network without connectivity being set between them. So, I planned to deploy required services on my new cluster.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: But, if in case there is a connectivity, how can we consume services between cluster? Shall we use ingress?

Sorry, if it is simple or dumb question, I am new to devops and kubernetes, so all this is killing me to understand :(

Comment: @abindlish this will depend on your Kubernetes solution. I couldn't find in the question or in the comments what exact Kubernetes solution are you using. Is it a cloud-managed one like `GKE`, `AKS`, `EKS` or on-premise one? With the cloud managed, I'd reckon you could look on terms like: *Internal loadbalancer*, *Internal Ingress* and *Nodeport* depending on the provider used.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what `ExternalName` services are for.

`ExternalName` services are used to have a cluster internal service name that forwards traffic to another (internal or external) DNS name. In practice what an `ExternalName` does is create a CNAME record that maps the external DNS name to a cluster-local name. It does not expose anything out of your cluster. See [documenation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname).

What you need to do is expose your services outside of your kubernetes clusters and they will become usable from the other cluster as well.

There are different ways of doing this.
For example:

- [`NodePort service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport): when using a NodePort, your service will be exposed on each node in the cluster on a random high port (by default in the 30000-32767 range). If your firewall allows traffic to such port you could reach your service from using that port.
- [`LoadBalancer service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): if you are running kubernetes in an environment that supports Load Balancer allocation you could expose your service to the internet using a load balancer.
- [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/): if you have an ingress controller running in your cluster you could expose your workload using an `Ingress`.

On the other cluster, you could simply reach the service exposed.

Comment: what if you want to refer in the externalName a private service on the second cluster through a peered vnet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922517/aks-connect-to-external-service-on-a-different-aks-cluster-on-private-network