# AKS: connect to external service on a different aks cluster on private network

Tags: azure, dns, azure-aks, vnet

my goal is to call a service on an aks cluster (aks1) from a pod or a service on a second aks cluster (aks2).
These clusters will be on different regions and should communicate over a private network.

Azure CNI plugin.

So, after some reading and some video listening, it seemed for me that the best option was to use an externalName service on AKS2 calling a service defined in a custom private DNS zone (*ecommerce.private.eu.dev*), being these two VNets paired before.

```
This seems the vnet giving the address space to aks services:
dev-vnet  10.0.0.0/14

=======================================
dev-test1-aks   v1.22.4 - 1 node
dev-test1-vnet  11.0.0.0/16

dev-test2-aks   v1.22.4 - 1 node
dev-test2-vnet  11.1.0.0/16
```

After a lot of trials all I can get is connectivity between pods networks and never to reach the service network from the other cluster.

- I don't see any active firewall
- I've peered all three networks: dev-test1-vnet, dev-test2-vnet, dev-vnet (services CIDR)
- I've create a Private DNS zones private.eu.dev where I've put the "ecommerce" A record (10.0.129.155) that should be resolved by the externalName service

dev-test1-aks (EU cluster):

```
kubectl create deployment eu-ecommerce --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080 --replicas=1
kubectl expose deployment eu-ecommerce --type=ClusterIP --port=8080 --name=eu-ecommerce
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
kubectl create ingress eu-ecommerce --class=nginx --rule=eu.ecommerce/*=eu-ecommerce:8080 -o yaml --dry-run=client
```

This is the ingress rule:

```
❯ kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks get ingress eu-ecommerce-2 -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: eu-ecommerce-2
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: lb.private.eu.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: eu-ecommerce
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /ecommerce
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 20.xxxxx
```

This is one of the externalName I've tried on dev-test2-aks:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eu-services
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: ecommerce.private.eu.dev
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
```

These are some of my tests:

```
# --- Test externalName 
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://eu-services:8080
: '
    wget: cant connect to remote host (10.0.129.155): Connection timed out
'

# --- Test connectivity AKS1 -> eu-ecommerce service
kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://eu-ecommerce:8080
kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://10.0.129.155:8080
kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://eu-ecommerce.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://ecommerce.private.eu.dev:8080
# OK client_address=11.0.0.11

# --- Test connectivity AKS2 -> eu-ecommerce POD
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://11.0.0.103:8080
#> OK

# --- Test connectivity AKS2 -> eu-ecommerce service
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://ecommerce.private.eu.dev:8080
#> FAIL
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget -qO- http://10.0.129.155:8080


# --- Test connectivity - LB private IP
kubectl --context=dev-test1-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget --no-cache -qO- http://lb.private.eu.dev/ecommerce
#> OK
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- wget --no-cache -qO- http://lb.private.eu.dev/ecommerce
#> KO  wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.11.164): Connection timed out


# --- Traceroute gives no informations
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks  run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- traceroute -n -m4 ecommerce.private.eu.dev
: '
    *  *  *
    3  *  *  *
    4  *  *  *
'

# --- test2-aks can see the private dns zone and resolve the hostname
kubectl --context=dev-test2-aks run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox -- nslookup ecommerce.private.eu.dev
: ' Server:    10.0.0.10
    Address 1: 10.0.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
    Name:      ecommerce.private.eu.dev
    Address 1: 10.0.129.155
'
```

I've also created inbound and outbound **[network policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview)** for the aks networks:

- on dev-aks (10.0/16) allow all incoming from 11.1/16 and 11.0/16
- on dev-test2-aks allow any outbound

Seen *docs*:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#virtual-network-peering
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-portal#create-a-private-dns-zone
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4S6AxYNDtM

Comment: You should move your question to SeverFault

Comment: Which network plugin are you using? Kubenet or Azure CNI? Also, which kind of routing are you relying on (load balancer or udr)?

Comment: Azure CNI and standard load balancer. I can connect directly to a pod on a second cluster, but can't access the services (10.0.0.0/16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using an [internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#create-an-internal-load-balancer) on the peered VNet.

This address is routable and reachable from a peered network. So you can still use an externalName or externalIP to reach it from the other cluster services

Answer (score 0):

In AKS the service CIDR is not part of your vnet address space and therefore it is not routed by Azure in any way so you won't be able to connect from a pod directly to a service in another cluster.

What you have to do is:

1. Expose your service using i.e. an ingress (which i think you are trying to do but the commands show only generating a yaml for ingress rule not the actual creation of ingress rule)
2. A-record in your privat DNS zone should point to the private IP address of your load balancer not your service IP address

With this your high-level communication scheme would look like this: (aks1)pod -> (aks2)lb -> (aks2)ingress -> (aks2)service -> (aks2)pods

Comment: If you double check my command list I've actually deployed an nginx ingress controller and also tested connectivity to the private LB IP (lb.private.eu.dev) which is exactly an A record added to a private DNS zone. The domain is resolved correctly but then the connection dies for timeout

Comment: Yes, indeed you are deploying an ingress controller but you are not deploying an ingress rule which is essential

Comment: I have also the ingress rule, I forgot to put the command here, but you can deduct that from the dev-test1-aks run wget lb.private.eu.dev/ecommerce working fine. Also the error is a connection timeout and not a 500 or 404 coming from a missing ingress rule. Probably that was not clear, thanks